# Java ME - Multiple forms, moving from one screen to the next

Tags: java-me, midp, lcdui

I am using Java Micro Edition and I am trying to create a simple login form with a record store. When the user enters the details I'd like to check them against the ones stored and then move onto another screen like a welcome area.

I have a feeling it has something to do with the form element and switching between it but I can't seem to get anywhere with google

Answer (score 3, accepted):

display is something that should be created in the constructor and also above it i.e.

```
public class YourMidlet extends MIDlet implements CommandListener {

    private Display display;
    private Form form1;
    private Form form2;

    public YourMidlet 
    {
        display = Display.getDisplay(this);
        form 1 = new Form("hello form this is form 1");
        form 2 = new Form("hello form 2");
        display.setCurrent(form1);
    }

}
```

you then do:

```
display.setCurrent(form2);
```

to switch to form 2

Answer (score 5):

try this

```
form = new Form("login");
form.addCommand(getExitCommand());
form.addCommand(getOkCommand());
form.setCommandListener(this);

public void commandAction(Command command, Displayable displayable) {
    if (displayable == form) {
        if (command == exitCommand) {
            exitMIDlet();
        } else if (command == okCommand) {
            display.setCurrent(getWelcomeForm());
        }
    } else if (displayable == form1) {
        if (command == backCommand) {
            // do something else
        }
    }
}
```